# Async keyword introduce huge performance decrease

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to understand async/await but I discovered this.
The two code below only differ from the keyword `async`

```
void main() {
  asyncAwait();
}

void asyncAwait() {
  int i = 0;
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  print(" Now ");
  while (i++ < 10000000000);
  DateTime after = DateTime.now();
  print("Done in ${after.difference(now)}");
}
```

> Now  Done in 0:00:09.222742

```
void main() {
  asyncAwait();
}

void asyncAwait() async {
  int i = 0;
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  print(" Now ");
  while (i++ < 10000000000);
  DateTime after = DateTime.now();
  print("Done in ${after.difference(now)}");
}
```

> Now  Done in 0:00:30.555924

One is at least 3 times faster than the other. I am looking for an explanation at the compiler level but I could not find any documentation about so.

I run it with this command with dart  2.13.0

```
dart main.dart
```

If you don't see a huge difference, chance 10000000000 to 100000000000

Comment: What version of Dart are you using to make (kinda useless...) test? Also, how are you running the two programs? Because when using Dart 2.14.4 and compiling both programs with "dart compile exe" and then execute them, I get the exact same running time.

Comment: I see a small difference (but not much) when running via `dart`.  I do see a more pronounced difference when running via DartPad.  The difference in reported times seems rather surprising to me since Dart executes `async` functions synchronously as much as possible, and your function is entirely synchronous.

Comment: The time difference is large enough that this shouldn't matter too much, but it's worth noting that the use of a `Stopwatch` for benchmarks is much more appropriate than `DateTime`.

Comment: @jamesdlin I added more info to see the huge difference. And FYI, this isn't "kinda  useless" because there are a lot of places where developers of our repo forget to remove the `async` keyword after refactoring their code changing an `asynchronous` function to `synchronous` and the static analyisis does not complain about leaving that keyword there, so this test has identified a bottleneck in performance

Comment: @TSR On my system, running `dart main.dart` gives me times of ~6s (without `async`) and ~9s (with `async`). For me, changing the number of iterations just changes those times linearly.

Comment: maybe its worth noting that when running in `release` mode (10 loops with/without `async` keyword) the `async` version is faster by a factor of `0.9901890153290556` - that is if "normal" method takes 100 seconds the `async` version takes ~99 seconds

Comment: I also see no difference with release binaries generated from `dart compile`, so my guess is that the slowdown observed in debug builds is from additional debugging information generated for `async` functions.